# Dependabot not adding Team as reviewer

Tags: github, npm, dependabot

I have implemented dependabot in my org repo.
Dependabot is creating pull requests all fine. But it's not adding any team reviewers, there are no error logs on PR or in Dependency graph> dependabot.

My yml config:-

```
version: 2
updates:

  # Maintain dependencies for login
  - package-ecosystem: "npm"
    directory: "/login"
    schedule:
      interval: "monthly"
    reviewers:
      - "org/cloud-reviewers"
    pull-request-branch-name:
      separator: "-"
    target-branch: "dev"
    open-pull-requests-limit: 5
```

Comment: What was the root cause, from the ones I mention below in the answer you just accepted?

Comment: The issue was not having the correct permissions to that Team I was using for PR review.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that since July 2020, you can "[assign a GitHub team to review Dependabot pull requests](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-15-assign-a-github-team-to-review-dependabot-pull-requests/)".

But the [Configure `dependabot.yml` / `reviewers`](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#reviewers) section includes:

> You must use the full team name, including the organization, as if you were `@mentioning` the team.

So double-check if `org/cloud-reviewers` is the right id (try and @ mention that account in a comment for instance)
And check if the [permission level](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/permission-levels-for-a-personal-account-repository) include submitting a [PR review](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/reviewing-proposed-changes-in-a-pull-request).

---

The [OP Nandan Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11424108/nandan-raj) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72797235/dependabot-not-adding-team-as-reviewer?noredirect=1#comment130027041_72797235) an issue with not having the correct permissions to the Team used for PR review.